# Solr facet breaks attribute name

Tags: solr, facet

I have a solr schema like the following:
...


...

I want to pull all possible grand_cat ( grand category) from solr, so i did a facet search
which did a count of all grand_cat; the problem is it will split all grand_cat strings.

for example, the grand category "foo and bar" will be split into "foo", "and", "bar"

is there a way to do this like in sql: select distinct (field) from myTable?

thanks
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out that if the grand_cat field will not split value if it is has a type of String instead of text_general.